# Basic Network Routing Question

Tags: networking, server, routing

I guess this is a very basic (dumb) question about routing. If I specify a route do I need to worry about a return path or does that also need to be specified?

For example I have a WiFi hotspot on wlan0 for which the routing table shows  having a destination of 10.10.0.0

If I add a routing table path from 10.10.0.0 to localhost then I assume traffic coming from wlan0 will be routed to localhost. When the server at localhost responds will that return route be handled automatically or do I need to also specify that route somehow too?

Comment: You do not need to worry about return path, except in some special cases.